# Время ответа сервера. Opencart 3

Tags: opencart

Подскажите пожалуйста как уменьшить время ответа сервера. Opencart3. Вроде бы все то в инете было сделал, кроме скриптов асинхронных, потому что модули бывает не догружает и страница не полная получается. Подсчет товаров в категориях убрал, галочки главное меню убрал в категориях тоже, изображения подрезал, лишние модули повыключал. Через 6-7 секунд только начинается загузка. Такое ощущение что все картинки сайта грузит на главной странице.

thebionica.top

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Такое ощущение что все картинки сайта грузит на главной странице.

Практически так и есть , по всей видимости , у Вас в этом блоке ( ниже скриншот ) подгружаются на страницу все существующие товары за один раз.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Избавьтесь временно от этого блока или же перепилите его реализацию , нужно как минимум что - то похожее на пагинацию. Т.е загружать первоначально по 4 - 8 товаров , а далее уже , например , аяксом догружать следующую пачку при клике на кнопку навигации.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все теперь отлично грузит!